# Regex to match a string with multiple occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex, match

> It's a [foo] and a bar and a [bar] and a [foo] too.

I want to match the strings inside each square bracket.

the matched array will be as **foo,bar,foo**

I tried `match(/\[(.*)\]/g)`, but the output is getting as "[foo] and a bar and a [bar] and a [foo]". It match with the very first '[' and very last ']'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below code which matches the strings present inside the `[]` brackets,

```
"It's a [foo] and a bar and a [bar] and a [foo] too".match(/[^\[\]]+(?=\])/g)
[foo,bar,foo]
```